# Put Text on Absolute position in PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to edit an existing PDF and want to add new text on top of an [image: Table in PDF]

I am trying below code:

```
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText();
            // write the text in the pdf content
            cb.BeginText();
            Phrase p = new Phrase(BrokerName);            
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(p, lxValue, lyValue, uxValue, uyValue, leadingValue, textAlign);
```

But When trying to edit PDF with new Text. I am able to insert new text but it comes under table as highlighted in below image.

```
Because Body section of table is encrypted. So I is it possible to Edit/Remove that portion?
```

Comment: Where do you get your values for lx, ly, ux, uy from?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `cb` is a `PdfContentByte` instance you retrieve from a `PdfStamper` using its `GetUnderContent(int pageNum)` method.

As the method name `GetUnderContent` already indicates, it is there for adding content *under* what already exists, and if the existing content opaquely covers the area, you won't see your additions.

If you want to add new content *above* the existing content, you should use the `PdfContentByte` instance returned by `GetOverContent(int pageNum)` instead.

---

*If the assumption above is wrong, please extend your question to provide enough information to answer without guessing...*